# Using Numpy's random.choice to randomly remove item from list

Tags: python, numpy, random

According to the http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html, using the `replace = False` with Numpy's `random.choice` method should make the sample without replacement. However, this does not seem to work for me:

```
In [33]: import numpy as np

In [34]: arr = range(5)

In [35]: number = np.random.choice(arr, replace = False)

In [36]: arr
Out[36]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The array `arr` is still `range(5)` after sampling, and not missing a (random) number as I would expect. How could I sample a number from `range(5)` without replacement?

Comment: `np.random.choice` does not mutate the original array. It's not literally sampling from the array.

Comment: You are not assigning it back to `arr`.

Comment: @Divakar that would be the complement of what OP is looking for.

Comment: "How could I sample a number from range(5) without replacement?" for a single number, "with or without" part is not important. If you want to sample two numbers, you'd just do `np.random.choice(arr, 2, replace=False)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well I am not sure what OP is looking for, but since OP mentioned : `array arr is still range(5)`, hence my earlier comment.

Comment: @Divakar OP was expecting that the original sequence passed to `np.random.choice` would have random elements *removed*. Instead, OP observed that the original sequence was "not missing a (random) number as I would expect"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, np.choice selects with or without replacement, a series of numbers from a sequence. But it does not modify the sequence.

**Easy alternative**

```
arr = range(5)
# numbers below will never contain repeated numbers (replace=False)
numbers = np.random.choice(arr, 3, replace=False)
```

The behaviour I think you want would be:

```
arr = range(5)
all_but_one = np.random.choice(arr, len(arr) -1, replace=False)
```

so you would select N-1 numbers without replacement (to avoid repetitions), effectively removing a random element from the iterable.

**More efficient alternative**

```
arr = range(5)
random_index = np.random.randint(0, len(arr))
arr.pop(random_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up defining a function using the `random` library:

```
import random
def sample_without_replacement(arr):
    random.shuffle(arr)
    return arr.pop()
```

Its use is shown below:

```
In [51]: arr = range(5)

In [52]: number = sample_without_replacement(arr)

In [53]: number
Out[53]: 4

In [54]: arr
Out[54]: [2, 0, 1, 3]
```

Note that the method also shuffles the array in place, but for my purposes that doesn't matter.